# Xcode: Add LaunchScreen without Storyboard

Tags: xcode, info.plist, launch-screen, xcode14

I try to add a LaunchScreen in Xcode (Version 14.0.1) without using Storyboard.

I followed the [Launch screens in Xcode: All the options explained](https://www.avanderlee.com/xcode/launch-screen/) article Chapter "*Using a plist configuration*"

**1. I added an image asset named "LaunchScreen"**

[image: Image Asset]

**2. In Info.plist, I added the Key "Launch Screen" inside the "Information Property List"**

[image: Info.plist]

**3. I deleted “Launch screen interface file base name” Key in Custom iOS Target Properties**

[image: iOS Target Properties]

Unfortunately the LaunchScreen is not shown at start up.

Comment: Bro, I tried to reproduce your problem. It just behaves as the blog said. Could you please compare my project with yours? https://github.com/kasimok/73952666

Comment: Sorry for the late response and thank you for the effort! But believe it or not, I just saw the launch image once in your sample project. Now I just see a black screen again. Sometimes after rebuild and clean up the project I see your launchScreen, but very distorted.

Comment: Same behavior on a real device, but I mentioned a short flickering. Maybe the Launch Screen is just there for a few ms and disappears too early. Maybe this can not be reproduced in the simulator. I will go ahead with testing.

Comment: Very interesting... The launch screen appearance seems to be different on different iPhone devices. iPhone 14Pro always shows black, iPhone 14Plus is very distorted and iPhone 14 works correctly.

Comment: Yeah, as the author already said: "As of today, it seems that the feature is still a work in progress." Now I believe him, cause I have to change the bundle ID every time I want to make change to the launch screen on some machine.  At least in Fall, 2022, it is still full of problems.